While browsing, is there a way that I can apply a CSS rule to an element in an iframe in a page I'm looking at with a bookmarklet or similar?
With https://jsfiddle.net/jfhs5g40/ as an example page, highly simplified from the actual scenario.
Using the following bookmarklet, I can change the CSS of the jsfiddle header, but not the make-me-red class that is in the jsfiddle results window iframe (it gives a DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object error).
javascript: (() => {
    let s = document.createElement("style");
    s.innerText = "#actions .actionCont { background: red; } ";
    document.head.appendChild(s);

    let s2 = document.createElement("style");
    s2.innerText = ".make-me-red { background: red; } ";
    frames[0].document.head.appendChild(s2);
})();

If I inspect element on the .make-me-red div in the iframe, then in the browser developer tools, I can add color: red; to the existing .make-me-red CSS rule with no issues.
The solution doesn't have to be a bookmarklet, but ideally I want to be able to shorten my current process (find elements on page, inspect each element, find and edit the relevant CSS rule(s)) to a single button click that adds the CSS in the iframe.
A couple of final things to note:

The iframe is not on the same domain as the main page
I do not have any control over or access to the main page or the page being loaded in the iframe. The solution would need to work from your browser, applying to the unmodified example jsfiddle


frames.document.head.appendChild can't work - frames returns a list of window instances, you need to pick a specific one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames#examples

Edited, but that gives me DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object.

That would be the Same Origin Policy at play. Not sure if you can circumvent that somehow in a bookmarklet context; Im guessing it might "inherit" the origin of the main document.

I haven't been able to find a way to circumvent it in a bookmarklet context, but the solution doesn't have to be a bookmarklet. Given that I can do it manually in developer tools, I'm hoping there's a way to automate it somehow.

Your best bet is probably to go find yourself a browser extension, that allows you to insert custom styling into web pages - something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customcss-injector/
